# Compass and straight-edge construction of a line

Tags: geometry

How to construct a line of given length L whose two ends lie on two fixed circles of radii b and c and centers of the circles being at a distance a from each other? Two different cases of construction required.
1. The required line is parallel to the line joining the centers.
2. The required line makes an angle $\theta$ with the line joining the centers.

Assuming such a line exists in each case. Am trying to attach this diagram. But the description is complete without it.
[https://www.geogebra.or/upload/5c9b620b11fd4](https://www.geogebra.org/upload/5c9b620b11fd4)

Comment: The page is not accessible.

Comment: Hi Yves, sorry - I am new to this site. Haven't yet learnt how to upload a picture. I bungled it this time. I hope to learn it quickly.

Answer (score 1):

First problem:

1. Draw a line joining the centers. Suppose it intersects circles at points A and B respectively.
2. Do a bisection of A and B, let it be point C.
3. Put points D and E on AB (opposite sides of C), such that DC=L/2 and EC=L/2.
4. Draw lines orthogonal to AB through points D and E. Suppose that these lines intersect circles at F and G.
5. Connect F and G - you've got the answer.

All this assuming that solution exists.

Comment: Hi Alex, looks to me that your solution would work if the circles are of same radius. But if they are of different radius, then FG is not parallel to the line joining the centers and also does not have a length L. Correct me if I am wrong.